# iOS Permission - Ideal Microphone Permission Dialog Text

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios-permissions

I have a chat app, and that has an upload function in which the user can upload photos and videos from the gallery or capture one. On iOS, to record video, one needs microphone permission separately (why? - isn't it obvious?). Now whenever I'm trying to submit to App Store, my binary is being rejected because they say:

> We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access their microphone but does not clarify the use of the microphone in the permission modal alert.

My current permission modal alert text (after several changes) is

> Enable microphone access so that you can be heard in the video

And even this latest one was rejected. Is there a better text that I can provide which may be perceived as clearer and my app may pass the review?

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/cr8resume/revise-the-permission-modal-alert-to-specify-why-the-app-is-requesting-access-to-the-users-location-737df30baba9) might help you..

Comment: Thanks, but it dosent have anything on microphone :( ... though I did read it and am considering revising it to 

```Enable microphone access to add sound in the video. The video will be stored locally and will only be uploaded if you choose to do it.```

Comment: I think it should be more like, `App would like to access your microphone to ...(specify your reason here)..`

Comment: Exactly. Apps do get rejected that "force" a user to select one option. You can't say: "Enable this" or "Do that". You have to simply say "The app uses x for y", and let the user choose 'enable' themselves, without pushing them.

Comment: @Ramon appreciate the suggestion, however, this and a few other permissions (e.g. Camera) were inspired by the permissions in Google Hangouts and Google Calendar (all permission texts go like "Enable <permission> <reason>"). Moreover, even the rejection does not mention the other permissions. 


I still keep your suggestion and request one major spoon feed: so what exactly should be my permission dialog message my app where I just need it to record a video which will be uploaded. (Again, this is a standard requirement in iOS to ask for microphone permission when one will record video)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an easy statement like :

> "This app requires the access to Microphone to record your voice memo."

I have this statement in one of my app and it was accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either of these:

**1.** "We need access to your microphone for adding sounds and uploading them".

**2.** "We need access to your microphone so that you can add sounds and upload them after choosing".

**3.** " '**Your ProductName/AppName**' uses your microphone to capture audio which is shared with other participants".

**4.** "We need access to your microphone so that you can record/hear voice messages".

Just simply define the reason why your app is using microphone, i think **Fourth one** might help you.

Comment: I strongly recommend variant 4. Apple review team just checks your plist, not how exactly you will use it in most cases.